# compress java strings (urls)

Tags: java, string, url, compression, web-crawler

i have a lot of urls to deal with. i store around 20'000'000 of them in a hashset. that makes some memory problems.

i tried to create a compressed string class:

```
import java.io.*;//file writer
import java.util.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

class CompressedString2 implements Serializable{
    private int originalSize;
    private byte[] cstring;



    public CompressedString2 (){
        compress("");
    }


    public CompressedString2 (String string){
        compress(string);
    }


    public void compress(String str){
        try {
            byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
            originalSize = bytes.length;

            ByteArrayOutputStream deflatedBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            DeflaterOutputStream dos = new DeflaterOutputStream(deflatedBytes,new Deflater(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION));
            dos.write(bytes);
            dos.finish();
            cstring=deflatedBytes.toByteArray();
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    }


    public String decompress() throws Exception{
        String result="";
        try{
            ByteArrayOutputStream deflatedBytes=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            deflatedBytes.write(cstring);
            deflatedBytes.close();


            InflaterInputStream iis = new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(deflatedBytes.toByteArray()));
            byte[] inflatedBytes = new byte[originalSize];
            iis.read(inflatedBytes);
            result= new String(inflatedBytes, "UTF-8");
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        return result;
    }
}
```

but in fact when i store them with something like this:

```
HashSet<String> urlStr=new HashSet<String>();
HashSet<CompressedString> urlComp=new HashSet<CompressedString>();


        String filePath=new String();

            filePath=args[0];

        int num=0;

        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {

                num++;
                urlStr.add(line);
                urlComp.add(new CompressedString(line));

            line = br.readLine();
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("fehler..:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

ObjectOutputStream oos1 = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("testDeflator_rawurls.obj"));
oos1.writeObject(urlStr);
ObjectOutputStream oos4 = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("testDeflator_compressed2.obj"));
oos4.writeObject(urlComp);
```

the "compressed" urls are even bigger...

does anybody have an idea how to successfully compress urls?

Comment: Well you were storing the urls as just strings before, now you would be storing them as `CompressedString` objects. Of course they are going to be bigger, while the url itself is compressed, your object is going to take up more memory than the string did.

Comment: @jzworkman -- I don't agree; the `CompressedString` contains an array and an `int`, and that's actually *fewer* members than a `String` has.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if they're in a set, then all you can do is add/remove/lookup. You could also do these operations on a "character forest", and it could be a more compact representation. I'm thinking of a tree of nodes, each holding one character, linked to one another. The roots of the forest would contain "h", "f", and a few more. Under the "h" node would be a "t" node, and another "t" under that, and a "p" under that, etc. The "f" node would have "t" and "i" children. Eventually the tree would branch off, but there could be a lot of sharing near the roots. Then you just walk the forest to find out if a URL is in there.

I suppose a node would need a boolean member to indicate that one of the URLs in the set terminated there, a member to hold the character, and an array of links to other nodes.

Comment: this could be fast, depending on implementation, (expected O(n) to traverse a URL, where n is the length of the url)

Comment: I might try implementing something like this, just for fun!

Comment: +1. Depending on the URLs, a "string forest" might work out better (in terms of lookup time and storage overhead). Roots like "http://" and "ftp://" followed by children splitting off at every "/".

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a different approach? 20 million strings in a hashset is a lot. Could you store them in a database and process it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Just a though, in general, for compression to work well, the strings have to be longer because it works based on patterns in said string.

Answer (score 0):

Short strings may not compress to being smaller than the uncompressed string.  Have you tried `-XX:+UseCompressedString` which is on by default for some versions of Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

You could compress n URLs at a time, where n may be 10's to 100's.  That would give the compressor something to work with in the way of repeated strings and skewed character probability distributions.  The downside is having to decompress 10's to 100's of URLs for each access.  So having implemented that, vary n to trade between memory usage and speed and pick a compromise you like.

Answer (score 0):

If many of your urls have a common base, for example `http://www.mysite.com/` then you should consider using [Ropes](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ropes/) ([project page](http://ahmadsoft.org/ropes/)) so that the first part of each string is represented once.

Also see [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use tinyurl to reduce the length and then store it. 
You can find the java utility class to tiny URL [here](http://www.mularien.com/blog/2008/12/04/tutorial-accessing-the-tinyurl-api-from-java/)

Answer (score 0):

What about concatenating 100 links together for example (separated by a special char) and try to compress them into one CompressedString ? 
Compression might need a minimum length in order to be efficient.
CompressedString class could restore the 100 strings in a Collection.

Answer (score 0):

Compressing the URLs will not necessarily save you any memory, due to the extra overhead of the wrapper class. An alternative approach would be to use a prefix map to shorten the URLs. However, if a wrapper class is used you must implement the `hashCode` and `equals` methods. Without them, the hash set will not work as intended (duplicates will be permitted). For `CompressedString2` these could be implemented as:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Arrays.hashCode(cstring);
}

public boolean equals(Object other){
    if(other instanceof CompressedString){
        return Arrays.equals(cstring, ((CompressedString) other).cstring);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Another thing that could drastically decrease the memory footprint is to use, for example, Trove's `THashSet`. Since you know the approximate number of URLs you can also increase the load factor and set the initial size of the hash set, which will save you a lot of rehashing and allow you to use the allocated space more efficiently.